# cvCalcEigenObjects in opencv?

Tags: opencv

Here's my code:

```c
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "legacy.h"
/*************************************************/
//Global variables
int nTrainFaces = 0;//number of training images
int nEigens = 0;//number of eigenvalues
IplImage** faceImgArr = 0;//array of face images
IplImage** eigenVectArr = 0;//eigenvectors
CvMat* personNumTruthMat;
CvMat* projectedTrainFaceMat;//projected training faces
CvMat* eigenValMat;//eigenvalues
IplImage* pAvgTrainImg = 0;
/*************************************************/
//Define methods
void learn();
int loadFaceImgArray(char* filename);
void doPCA();
void storeTrainingData();
void recognize();
int loadTrainingData(CvMat** pTrainPersonNumMat);
int findNearestNeighbor(float* projectedTestFace);
/*************************************************/
//Content of methods
void learn()
{
int i;
//load training data
nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("training_images.txt");
//do PCA on the training faces
doPCA();
//project the training images onto the PCA subspace
projectedTrainFaceMat = cvCreateMat(nTrainFaces,nEigens,CV_32FC1);
for(i = 0; i < nTrainFaces; i++)
{
    cvEigenDecomposite(
        faceImgArr[i],
        nEigens,
        eigenVectArr,
        0,NULL,
        pAvgTrainImg,
        projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl + i*nEigens
        );
}
//store the recognition data as an .xml file
storeTrainingData();
}
int loadFaceImgArray( char* filename)
{
FILE* imgListFile = 0;
char imgFilename[512];
int iFace,nFaces = 0;
//Open the input file
imgListFile = fopen(filename,"r");
//count number of faces
while(fgets(imgFilename,512,imgListFile))
    ++nFaces;
rewind(imgListFile);
//allocate the face-image array and person number matrix
faceImgArr = (IplImage**)cvAlloc(nFaces*sizeof(IplImage*));
personNumTruthMat = cvCreateMat(1,nFaces,CV_32SC1);
//Store the face images in an array
for(iFace = 0; iFace < nFaces; iFace++)
{
    //read person number and name of image file
    fscanf(
        imgListFile,
        "%d %s",
        personNumTruthMat->data.i + iFace,
        imgFilename
            );
    //load the face image
    faceImgArr[iFace] = cvLoadImage(imgFilename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
}
fclose(imgListFile);
return nFaces;
}
void doPCA()
{
int i;
CvTermCriteria calcLimit;
CvSize faceImgSize;
//set the number of eigenvalues to use
nEigens = nTrainFaces - 1;
//allocate the eigenvector images
//faceImgSize.width = faceImgArr[0]->width;
//faceImgSize.height = faceImgArr[0]->height;
faceImgSize.width = 170;
faceImgSize.height = 180;
eigenVectArr = (IplImage**)cvAlloc(nEigens*sizeof(IplImage));
for(i = 0; i < nEigens; i++)
    eigenVectArr[i] = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize,IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
//allocate the eigenvalue array
eigenValMat = cvCreateMat(1,nEigens,CV_32FC1);
//allocate the averaged image
pAvgTrainImg = cvCreateImage(faceImgSize,IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
//set the PCA termination criterion
calcLimit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,nEigens,1);
//compute average image, eigenvalues, and eugenvectors
cvCalcEigenObjects(
    nTrainFaces,
    (void*)faceImgArr,
    (void*)eigenVectArr,
    CV_EIGOBJ_NO_CALLBACK,
    0,0,
    &calcLimit,
    pAvgTrainImg,
    eigenValMat->data.fl
    );
}
void storeTrainingData()
{
CvFileStorage* fileStorage;
int i;
//create a file-storage interface
fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage("facedata.xml",0,CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
//store all the data
cvWriteInt(fileStorage,"nEigens",nEigens);
cvWriteInt(fileStorage,"nTrainFaces",nTrainFaces);
cvWrite(fileStorage,"trainPersonNumMat",personNumTruthMat,cvAttrList(0,0));
cvWrite(fileStorage,"eigenValMat",eigenValMat,cvAttrList(0,0));
cvWrite(fileStorage,"projectedTrainFaceMat",projectedTrainFaceMat,cvAttrList(0,0));
cvWrite(fileStorage,"avgTrainImg",pAvgTrainImg,cvAttrList(0,0));
for(i = 0; i < nEigens; i++)
{
    char varname[200];
    sprintf(varname,"eigenVect_%d",i);
    cvWrite(fileStorage,varname, eigenVectArr[i],cvAttrList(0,0));
}
//release the file-storage interface
cvReleaseFileStorage(&fileStorage);
}
void recognize(IplImage* TestImg)
{
CvMat* trainPersonNumMat = 0;
float* projectedTestFace = 0;
//load the saved training data
if(!loadTrainingData(&trainPersonNumMat))
    return;

projectedTestFace = (float*)cvAlloc(nEigens*sizeof(float));

int iNearest,nearest;
//project the test images onto the PCA subspace
cvEigenDecomposite(
    TestImg,
    nEigens,
    eigenVectArr,
    0,0,
    pAvgTrainImg,
    projectedTestFace
    );
iNearest = findNearestNeighbor(projectedTestFace);
nearest = trainPersonNumMat->data.i[iNearest ];
printf("nearest = %d",nearest);
}
int loadTrainingData(CvMat** pTrainPersonNumMat)
{
CvFileStorage* fileStorage;
int i;
//create a file-storage interface
fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage("facedata.xml",0,CV_STORAGE_READ);
if(!fileStorage)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't open facedata.xml \n");
    return 0;
}
nEigens = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage,0,"nEigens",0);
nTrainFaces = cvReadIntByName(fileStorage,0,"nTrainFaces",0);
*pTrainPersonNumMat = (CvMat*)cvReadByName(fileStorage,0,"trainPersonNumMat",0);
eigenValMat = (CvMat*)cvReadByName(fileStorage,0,"eigenValMat",0);
projectedTrainFaceMat = (CvMat*)cvReadByName(fileStorage,0,"projectedTrainFaceMat",0);
pAvgTrainImg = (IplImage*)cvReadByName(fileStorage,0,"avgTrainImg",0);
eigenVectArr = (IplImage**)cvAlloc(nTrainFaces*sizeof(IplImage*));
for(i = 0; i < nEigens; i++)
{
    char varname[200];
    sprintf(varname,"eigenVect_%d",i);
    eigenVectArr[i] = (IplImage*)cvReadByName(fileStorage,0,varname,0);
}
//release the file-storage interface
cvReleaseFileStorage(&fileStorage);
return 1;
}
int findNearestNeighbor(float* projectedTestFace)
{
double leastDistSq,distSq = 0;
int i,iTrain,iNearest = 0;
for(i = 0; i < nEigens; i++)
{
    float d_i = projectedTestFace[i] - projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl[i];
    distSq +=d_i*d_i;
}
leastDistSq = distSq;
iNearest = 0;
for(iTrain = 1;iTrain < nTrainFaces; iTrain++ )
{
    distSq = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < nEigens; i++)
    {
        float d_i = projectedTestFace[i] -     projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i];
        distSq +=d_i*d_i;
    }
    if(distSq < leastDistSq)
    {
        leastDistSq = distSq;
        iNearest = iTrain;
    }
}
return iNearest;
}
/*************************************************/
//Main function
int main()
{

learn();
//IplImage* test_img = cvLoadImage("D:\document\Study\university of technology\semester_8\Computer Vision\Pics for test\faces\face1.bmp");
//recognize(test_img);
return 0;
}
```

When debugging, there's an error at function `cvCalcEigenObjects` as follow:

OpenCV error: Bad argument  in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 1070

How can I fix this error ? hope for help! I've done many searches on internet but there's no effective solution.

---

here is the output of compiler!
[image]

Comment: Can you add the full output of the compiler to your question? or is that it.

Comment: the error line above is displayed on console window! in addition, there's a error window poping up, said that : "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Test.exe
Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.
"

Comment: i'm using opencv 2.4.4!

Comment: Try putting the full file path in for this line  nTrainFaces = loadFaceImgArray("training_images.txt");

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the width en height from faceImgSize at the doPCA function. This is because the width and height of each eigenvector image must be the same as the width and height of the input images. This should probably do the trick

Comment: i've assigned faceImgSize.width & height to a fixed value, the error still happened ! i think the problem here is the function "cvCalcEigenObjects", but i don't know what wrong with it ?